# Named query on child joining two levels of parent tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given

```
class Store {
    String name

    static hasMany = [departments: Department]
}

class Department {

    String name

    static belongsTo = [store: Store]

    static hasMany = [products: Product]

}

class Product {
    String name
    Integer qty

    static namedQueries = {
        productsInStockByStore {store->
            department {
                store {
                    eq 'id', store.id
                }
            }
            gt 'qty', 0
        }
    }

    static belongsTo = [department: Department]

}
```

I get an error running:

```
def store = Store.first() // just for the sake of testing
Product.productsInStockByStore(store).list()
```

> No signature of method: namedboom.Store.call() is applicable for
>   argument types:
>   (namedboom.Product$__clinit__closure1$_closure3$_closure4$_closure5)
>   values:
>   [namedboom.Product$__clinit__closure1$_closure3$_closure4$_closure5@768aab6a]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), last(), save(), any(), getAll(),
>   wait(long)

What would be the right way to accomplish this with named query? The only way I could get it to work is using createCriteria and declaring joints for the parent tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may be because `store` is defined in  your named query. Try changing name of this variable in the named query, like

```
static namedQueries = {
    productsInStockByStore {storeInstance->
        department {
            store {
                eq 'id', storeInstance.id
            }
        }
        gt 'qty', 0
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, another question. Why didn't I ask this an hour ago? .. embarrassing.. Thanks!